# How to parse this line of information in Java?

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am developing an android application that needs to grab a lot of information from one page. 
I need to be able to grab that page and parse the infrmation on it. At the beginning of the page there is two lines that I do not want to be included in the information parse.
The information is formatted like so:
**INFO I NEED 1** (Tab) **INFO I NEED 2** (Tab)... and so on.
I need each "INFO I NEED" assigned to a different variable... like "INFO I NEED 1" to variable1. 
Each new line has a string of information I need. So I need to be able to grab all of these lines and parse them out into variables to display on the page.
The infomation can be found here: http://master2.blockland.us/ 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the split method;

```
String theWholeData = "INFO I NEED 1 \t INFO I NEED 2 \t INFO I NEED 3";
String splittedData[] = theWholeData.split("\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a split method.

You call it in the string:

1 - retrieve the data you want

2 - assign it to a string array:

```
String data[] = originalString.split("\t");
```

3 - use each element in the array as you wish, using
a `for` loop.

The split method can separate your String with any elements you wish,
in this case, using the `<tab>`